# How to remove wallets from mist?

Tags: wallets, mist, accounts, mac-osx

I'm running Mist Wallet 0.5.2 on OSX.

In both the Wallets and the Contracts views, there is no trash icon to delete the respective Wallet or Contract. Same goes for the particular Account or Contract view. Tutorials reference this icon, but it's nowhere to be seen.

I know I can delete a particular Account from the Keystore folder. However, how do I go about deleting a Contract that I am currently watching? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click on the contract name on the main page and then hover over the name on the contract page you will see a trash icon that allows you to delete it.

Comment: how to delete all the contracts?

Answer (score 0):

Delete Custom Contract

open the console (or just right click any where on the mist and click the open developmer tool and go to the console tab)

type in : CustomContracts.find().fetch()

it will return all the contract you have in your mist.
look at the contract you want to remove and copy its _id.

Then type: 
CustomContracts.remove('the_id_you_copied')

and voila, the contract will be gone.